# Net-SNMP Application

Tags: files, snmp

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but, does anyone knows about Net-SNMP. Is it possible to not truncate the log file whenever snmptrapd is restarted?

The logs are being rotated by logrotate. But whenever I restart the snmp listener using this command:

```
/etc/init.d/snmptrapd restart
```

Or using this:

```
/etc/init.d/snmptrapd start
```

The log file for snmptrapd is being restarted to 0KB (restarted), previous logs are being deleted. We don't want that to happen.

Comment: What exact operating system, what exact versions? Why do you want to discard old logs uncondicionally, and not e.g. rotate them?

Comment: OS is linux. Actually, we really don't like to discard old logs thus the question on how we can modified the default behavior of the Net-SNMP listener truncating its log file whenever it is restarted. The goal is to append log files even the snmp listener is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-A` option:

> Append to the log file rather than truncating it. 
>   Note that this needs to come before any -Lf options that it should apply to.

(via http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmptrapd.html)